# SSE won't display messages in my chat application with react and express

Tags: reactjs, express, chat, prisma, server-sent-events

I want to open a SSE connection with Express for my live chat application. De SSE connection works because my Client (React) console receives messages and displays it in the console. The problem Im having right now is that the new messages won't be displayed on the page on other tabs. How do i solve this?

//Server.js (Express)

```
const express = require('express');
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let sseClients = [];

app.get('/api/sse', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
  res.flushHeaders();

  sseClients.push(res);


  // Handle client disconnect
  req.on('close', () => {

    sseClients = sseClients.filter((client) => client !== res);
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
});
```

// Chat.js (React)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MessageInput from '../components/messageinput/messageInput';
import MessageList from '../components/messagelist/MessageList';
import './chat.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001/api',
});

const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light'); // Default mode is 'light'
  const [buttonLabel, setButtonLabel] = useState('light');

  const toggleMode = () => {
    setMode((prevMode) => (prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
    setButtonLabel((prevLabel) => (prevLabel === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
  };

  const fetchMessages = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await instance.get('/messages');
      setMessages(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching messages:', error);
    }
  };

  // const addNewMessage = (newMessage) => {
  //   setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessage]);
  // };

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:3001/api/sse');
  
    // Fetch existing messages when the component mounts
    fetchMessages();
  
    eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log('EventSource connected successfully');
    };
  
    eventSource.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      console.log('Received SSE event:', event);
      const eventData = JSON.parse(event.data);
  
      // Handle the SSE event based on its type
      if (eventData.event === 'message') {
        console.log('Received SSE message:', eventData.data);
        // Update messages state with the new message
        setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, eventData.data]);
      }
    });
  
    eventSource.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
      console.error('EventSource failed:', error);
      eventSource.close();
    });
  
    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, [setMessages]); // Include setMessages as a dependency
  
  
  

  const handleAddMessage = async ({ name, message }) => {
    try {
      await instance.post('/messages', { name, message });
      fetchMessages();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding message:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`App ${mode}`}>
      <h1>Chat Application</h1>
      <MessageInput onAddMessage={handleAddMessage} />
      <button onClick={toggleMode}>{buttonLabel}</button>
      <MessageList messages={messages} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: Please check the tag wiki for the [tag:sse] tag - I suspect you should heed it's advice and switch to server-sent-events. If neither is correct, please expand on what *you* are abbreviating as "SSE".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: those of us who follow [sse] have to edit the tags on a couple questions a week, from [sse] to [server-sent-events].  I asked on meta ([Stop users from tagging SSE and Server-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390150)) if the site could prevent obvious mistakes like this, but the back-end support doesn't currently exist and probably won't happen, so nothing came of it.  It's a known fact that many users don't read the tag mouseovers, especially but not limited to new users.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: And yes, reactjs is one of the tags that we regularly see with mis-tagged [sse] questions; in the context of reactjs and other web/JS stuff, SSE means [server-sent-events].

Comment: To solve this issue you have to change the handleAddMessage() to: 

  const handleAddMessage = async ({ name, message }) => {
    try {
      await instance.post('/messages', { name, message });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding message:', error);
    }
  };

Because if you remove the fetchMessages() in the try only the SSE is running.